# Split applications into different mixer channels

Tags: windows, audio, volume-mixer, digital-audio, mixer

I am using Windows.

I have a physical audio mixer with several channels with 1/4 inch inputs. Is there any way anyone knows of to split up applications into different quarter inch outputs, so I could connect them to the mixer? Like a USB device with the quarter inch outputs?

There are many times when I wish I could control the volumes of the different applications (audio player, game, browser, etc.) without having to exit the current application and right-clicking the speaker icon at the right of the task bar and clicking "volume mixer".

Thanks!

Comment: *"1/4 inch inputs"* -- Presumably this is a 1/4" TRS phono jack for a differential audio input?  Besides the "size" of the connector, you need to specify the type of connector, and even more important, the type of signal, e..g. line-level audio.  That's because it's more complex to convert the signal than swap the connector.  BTW you don't have to *"exit"* (i.e. terminate) an app to adjust audio volume.  Win7 is capable of multitasking.

Comment: @sawdust yes I mean TRS. I'm not surewhat you mean by the type of signal - I can say I have the Behringer Xenyx 802 mixer

Comment: *"type of signal"* -- Yours is audio, not video.  Yours is analog, not digital. Is it balanced or unbalanced? Is it mic-level or line-level?  The typical PC audio adapter (aka "sound card") only has line-level unbalanced outputs.using 3.5mm TRS (aka stereo) jacks.

Comment: @sawdust i have two mic level/line level inputs (xlr + 1/4 inch) and a couple other line level inputs (1/4 inch). Right now I just plug a stereo 3.5mm to dual (left/right) quarter inches cable from my computer output (3.5mm) to two mixer 1/4 inch inputs (left/right). Sorry if that doesn't help answer your questions... I'm not experienced at all with this stuff